# Link to one page if logged in and another page if not

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an image that I want to link to one page if the user is logged in and another page if they are not.

I believe this is the code I need to use.

```
 if( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page("builder") )
 {
   wp_redirect( site_url("/builder") );
exit;
 }
```

My problem is that I do not know how to incorporate the "if" code into the image link code.

```
<a href="http://zanifesto.com/membership-account/membership-levels/"><img src="http://zanifesto.com/wp-content/themes/theretailer-child/create.png" /></a>
```

How do you combine the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorter version

```
<a href="<?php echo ((!is_user_logged_in() && !is_page("builder"))) ? 'HERE_IS_YOUR_URL_FOR_NOT_LOGGED_IN_USER' : 'HERE_IS_YOUR_URL_FOR_LOGGED_IN_USER'; ?>"><img src="image_link"></a>
```

OR

```
<img src="<?php echo ((!is_user_logged_in() && !is_page("builder"))) ? 'HERE_IS_YOUR_IMAGE_URL_FOR_NOT_LOGGED_IN_USER' : 'HERE_IS_YOUR_IMAGE_URL_FOR_LOGGED_IN_USER'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_page("builder"))
{
     ?>
     <a href="http://zanifesto.com/membership-account/membership-levels/"><img src="HERE_IS_YOUR_IMAGE_URL_FOR_NOT_LOGGED_IN_USER" /></a>
     <?php
}
else
{
     ?>
     <a href="http://zanifesto.com/membership-account/membership-levels/"><img src="HERE_IS_YOUR_IMAGE_URL_FOR_LOGGED_IN_USER" /></a>
     <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it may helps you:

```
<a href="<?php echo ((!is_user_logged_in() && !is_page("builder"))) ? 'HERE_IS_YOUR_URL_FOR_NOT_LOGGED_IN_USER' : 'HERE_IS_YOUR_URL_FOR_LOGGED_IN_USER'; ?>"><img src="image_link"></a>
```

Thanks.